# Playoff Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Toronto Maple Leafs won 30 of 82 games last season (i.e., the 2014-2015 season), giving them a winning percentage of 37%. If we assume this means the probability of the Leafs winning any given game is 0.37, then we can predict how they would have done in a playoff series.

Answer the following questions to determine the probability that the Leafs would have won a best of 7 playoff series (i.e., won 4 games) had they made the playoffs last season.

a. Rephrase this question in terms of sequences of 0s and 1s. What is the shortest length of a sequence? What is the longest length of a sequence?

1 = Win 0 = Loss
Shortest: Win in first 4 games 1111 - Length 4
Longest: Win in 7 games 0001111 - Length 7

b. Calculate the number of sequences which correspond to the Leafs winning the series. (Note that the answer is not C(7, 4).
Leafs winning in 4, 5, 6, 7
in 4: 1 way
in 5: C(4, 3) = 4
in 6: C(5, 3) = 10
in 7: C(6, 3) = 20 
Number of ways they can win: 35 ways

c. Calculate the number of sequences as they relate to this problem. (Note that the answer is not 2727 as not all series would last 7 games.

Sort of confused for this question.. would it be 35 x 2 = 70?

d. Calculate the probability that the Leafs would win the series

e. What is your best guess for the probability that the Leafs will ever win the Stanley Cup again (the ultimate prize in the NHL)?

I'm having trouble with some parts (c, d, e) of this question. And I am not sure if what I did so far is completely correct either. Any assistance/solutions with explanations will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary that you follow this outline?  I think it is a lot easier to answer the question by imagining that all $7$ games are played (even if the winner is decided before the $7^{th}$ game).  Then compute the probability that your team wins exactly $4$ games, exactly $5$ games, and so on.

Comment: Side note:  I assume that question $e$ is facetious.  You can't answer that from the data given...first of all, the $.37$ is not fixed over time.  Secondly, it is silly to use the regular season record as a simple predictor of the success  probability in a finals game.  Third, even if you make a host of simplifying assumptions, you would still need to estimate the probability that the team gets into the Finals in the first place.  I expect the question was posed by a despondant Leafs fan.

Comment: How would u do d?

Comment: I dont understand how to 0.37 comes into play

Comment: Maybe the despondent fan does see a glimmer of light: assuming the NFL will last indefinitely, and so do the Leafs, and the Leafs' chance of winning is greater than $0$, the Leafs are statistically bound to win the cup *some* time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good (yes, for c it is indeed twice the answer for b, as the other team has just as many ways of winning, and there will always be a winner.

For d: this is of course just the probability of the Leafs winning in $4$ games, plus the probability of winning in $5$, etc.  Now, just as an example, to win in $5$ games they need to win $4$ times and lose once, and this can happen in $4$ ways as you already found in b. So, that is

$$(0.37)^4 \cdot (1-0.37)^1 \cdot 4$$

Comment: for the probabilty for winning in 5 games as shown above, would it be 0.37^4 or 0.37^3 since they MUST win the last game?

Comment: @Mus Yes, they must win the last game, but all that does is reduce the number of ways in whch they win 4 out of 5 games: instead of 5, it's just 4. But they must still win 4 games total, so you still get $0.37^4$